# web.config - How to serve jpg/png as webp and avif if exist in IIS web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, nginx-config, webp

Currently, I'm using:

```
location ~* ^(/.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|webp)$ {
  add_header Vary Accept;
  try_files $1.avif $1.webp $uri =404;
}
```

in nginx so that if it is going to load `image.jpg` or `image.png` and there is the avif format it will load `image.avif`. It will load `image.webp` if the avif doesn't exist and finally, if none of them exist, it will load the main image which can be jpg or png. Otherwise, a 404 page will return. Now I want to have it in `web.config` in IIS. Or the question could be `How to convert the code above from nginx format to web.config?`

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happened? _Aside:_ A potential issue with the Nginx directives as posted is that you don't appear to be checking for `avif` (or `webp`) browser support before rewriting the request (that may or may not be a concern depending on the app/demographic). However, you are setting the `Vary: Accept` header as if you _are_ conditionally sending the response based on browser support?

Comment: IIS built-in modules don’t offer such a feature, but you can develop your own module to achieve this.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, can you give an example of your needs? I will make demo for you.